# Running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have Developed an Applicatoin in ASP.NET with C# and I have used oracle database.
my prob is when I am running this application from visual studio 2012 it will throw error like

> *Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.*

but when I host this application in my local iis and make application pool enable 32bit is true then it's working fine.

can anyone please guid me how can I run this from visual studio.

Comment: install both 32 and 64-bit of Oracle client

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the ODP use the managed driver from Oracle.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/

Comment: This deserves a bit more explanation than just a link. The Oracle Managed Driver replaces the need to install the Oracle Client on the machine. The managed driver is entirely in .NET code instead of relying on external binaries, so it is able seamlessly work with both 64bit and 32bit applications with ease.

Comment: Your right manson. Maybe I have to say that the Managed-ODP is more conservative with error- and cursorhandling. If you encounter many "ORA-07445" problems (look in your alert.log) solve them first!

Comment: No OracleDbType.Object available:
The managed driver deprecates the Oracle.DbType.Object property, so we cannot use it.