# Running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

This question similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538561/run-oracle-client-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-machine)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509521/running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32-bit-oracle-client-installed)

I fixed this problem, but when I opened new project **Wcf service library**, I had that same problem, and all this changes that I had done before did't help me.

I tried every thing that I did before and even more but it didn't helped.

It is **important** to say that if I do the same in another project all work fine but in WcfServiceLibrary it doesn't work.In WcfServiceApplication it working too.

I use VS2012(4.5) Win7 (64), my Oracle clien 32, but in other project this is not a problem.

Maybe it because Wcf library project i don't know.
i just buil service that save datd from database and i get error on connection to db.

```
Error: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

My code

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=zxc;Password=zxc;Data Source=NXE";
    con.Open();//here i get error
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + Table;
    int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    String DataFromORL = "";
    int row = 0;
    while (reader.Read() && row < 50)
    {
        row++;
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            DataFromORL += reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly on `con.Open()` line?

Comment: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: Change the build platform target from "Any CPU" to 32-bit only and see if that doesn't help

Comment: No it is not helping,

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same issue.
for me issue got fixed by doing the following thing.
prior to this check whether you have installed both 32bit and 64bit Oracle clients to make it available in both environments.

for me the reason for getting this error.

> Error: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64-bit mode with the 32-bit Oracle client components installed.

is because of the environmental variables has only one installation location and it is 32bit installation location that's why the error is **This problem will occur when running in 64-bit mode with the 32-bit Oracle client components installed.**

so, to resolve this what I did is, I added 64-bit installation location also and restarted my visual studio. if it does not work try by restarting system also, we are supposed to add both bin directories available in Oracle client installation location that we specify while installing Oracle clients.

In my system location is like:

`32-bit C:\app\client\<user>\product\12.1.0\client_2\bin`
`64-bit C:\app\client\<user>\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin`